# Asking someone about the person, which is suitable. Has/is/did he come home?

Tags: grammar

Asking someone about the person, which is suitable.

> Has he come home?
>
> Is he come home?
>
> Did he come home?

Comment: Has he come home ? Did he come home ? Is he home ? But not, Is he come home ?

Answer (score 5):

In British English, *Has he come home?* asks about someone who is expected roughly at the time of speaking. *Did he come home?* asks about someone who might or might not have come home at some time in the past. *Is he come home?* is not found in modern English, but the present perfect of *come* might be found with forms of the verb *be* in some passages in the King James Bible.